# Angular Toggle View

Tags: angularjs, view, toggle

So I'm a bit new to Angular, and I'm wondering what best practice would be if I wanted to be able to toggle content completely away. So you would be able to view it, or toggle off to hide it. Sorta clean things up. Should I use a if statement, or maybe give the content two sides (one being empty) and be able to switch between them? What would be best?

Comment: looks like you are looking for the ng-route directive

Comment: ng-route is not a directive.

Comment: yep. my bad. its a module

Comment: I think you need to go through some Angular tutorials before coming to ask. At lease you should know what features Angular provides.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

View switching in angular can be done in a multitude of ways.  In order to do route based switching (switching based on the hash in the url).  Use a combination of the ngRoute module which helps you to configure routes through the use of the $routeProvider and the ngView directive.

$routeProvider docs:

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/provider/$routeProvider

ngView docs:

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/directive/ngView

Also you can hide/show, add/remove content via these directives

ngIf - will completely remove and destroy the scope of the content

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngIf

ngSwitch - will work similar to a switch statement in javascript.  This is used in conjunction with ngSwitchWhen and ngSwitchDefault. Like the ngIf directive this will also remove and destroy the scope of the content.

ngSwitch/ngSwitchWhen/ngSwitchDefault

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngSwitch

ngHide/ngShow - per the name these directives will simply toggle the classes ng-hide and ng-show respectively.  ng-hide has a css property of display: none.

ngShow:

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngShow

ngHide:

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngHide

The directives that completely remove the contents can be better for performance since the number of watchers in your app can accumulate fairly quickly. In most cases I'd suggest using the removal based directives for anything that has an evaluation of the scope beneath it and use the hide/show directives for simple static content display.

There are example usages of each of these directives on all the documentation links I've included.  Feel free to comment with questions.